# Can't change import file size in php - editing php.ini doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to increase the file import size on php7 running on localhost ampps on mac os X.
I've tried editing the php.ini but it doesn't change a thing. It still stays on 8M. Also tried to change it from phpmyadmin but didn't help either.

Tried different values but it doesn't help.

Anyone who has any clue what I could do or can advise?

Comment: Did you restart the server after editing?

Comment: What setting are you talking about? PHP doesn't have an import file size, it has `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`.

Comment: yessir. Server restarted. 
Upload_max_filesize as well as post_max_size in php.ini changed.

Comment: check for the php version and path of ini used
>php -i

And check if you are using the correct ini.

Comment: @sudhir php 7.3. Server - ampps. Quite sure it's correct ini but is there a way to double check it? Also - any way that something might be simply overriding it?

Comment: The command line client can have a different configuration, so I would check the output of `phpinfo()` in your browser rather than using the command line `php -i`. Look in there for the directives and see if they're changed. If any other configuration file loads after yours and has that directive it would override those changes, so also look for the list of configuration files near the top of the phpinfo() output.

Comment: To see `phpinfo()`, make a new file somewhere in your web folder (the root or any subdirectory)with the content `<?php phpinfo();` and load that through your web browser.